# Ruby on Rails deployment requirements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment

I have started to think in RoR as an option to develop my applications, but I don't know much about it. I usually deploy my applications to Windows XP or Vista based PCs and use SQL Server as database.

Which are the system requirements to develop a Ruby on Rails application?

Comment: Were you able to successfully setup a windows based environment??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Even a year ago, Ruby on Rails applications were obnoxiously hard to deploy. (And I say this as somebody who loves Rails.) But today, things are much easier. Unfortunately, I don't have any experience deploying Rails on Windows servers. I can, however, tell you about deploying on Linux.

The simplest setup is probably a Linux (or BSD machine) running Apache and Phusion Passenger.  Apache should be installed by default on most Linux servers, and Passenger has a nice [command-line installation tool](http://www.modrails.com/install.html).

For a database, I generally use MySQL, though PostgreSQL might be more suitable if you do lots of really complex queries. Again, MySQL will be installed on most Linux servers.

As for your actual deployment process, I'd recommend using [Capistrano](http://www.capify.org/). This allows you to push updated code to your server with a single command, update your database as necessary, and even revert to an older version of your code if something goes wrong.

The advantage of deploying on Windows is that you already understand it. The advantage to deploying on Linux is that lots of people are familiar with that setup, and will be able to help you past the most common problems. If you do decide to deploy on Windows, I'd make sure that you find a good support community to answer your questions. (The more you deviate from a typical Rails setup, the more you need to know to make things work. So even if you don't end up going with the biggest crowd, it helps to find a smaller crowd and follow them.)

Answer (score 1):

Deploying to Windows is certainly possible, but the tool support is not nearly as good as for Unix style operating systems.

There is an entire chapter about Windows deployments on the book "[Deploying Rails Applications: A Step-by-Step Guide](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/fr_deploy/deploying-rails-applications)" by Ezra Zygmuntowicz, Bruce Tate, and Clinton Begin . See also "[Deployment Strategies for Rails on Windows servers](http://www.napcs.com/howto/rails/deploy/index.html)" articles by Brian Hogan.

Answer (score 1):

You can develop Ruby/Rails applications on your PC right out of the box without any additional installation tools necessary beyond Ruby, Rails, Ruby Gems, and SQLite on the PC.    You don't even need a web server because script/server will get the job done for you (an implementation of a development web server in Ruby).

The deployment question is trickier but Rails is fairly mature in this regard you have both Capistrano and Phusion as options.

While a Windows deployment is possible, if you plan to host the application on the Internet you are either going to be deploying to virtualization environments (http://www.morphexchange.com, [www.herkugarden.com](http://www.herkugarden.com), [www.heroku.com](http://www.heroku.com), etc) or you will be dealing with Linux-based virtual hosts or Linux-based shared hosts.  The development environment actually integrates with your deployment environment agnostically if you use Capistrano or Phusion.

Practically speaking, I've had the most stable development environment on *NIX based systems.  Occasionally I run into the issue of a gem misbehaving depending on platform.  Since most of my work is deployed to the Internet, it just makes more sense that my development environment is as close to possible as my deployment environment.

If your intention is stick with Windows, then you would be better served using the same platform for both deployment and development.

Comment: I'll be deploying to intranets, and my clients won't install any server operating system. That's why I'll be using Win XP or Vista. 
Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm stuck getting this all to work nicely on Windows. Maybe I'll save somebody some time.

I installed rails ok using instructions here - http://rubyonrails.org/download

However I had one issue in those instructions:
Then I ran gem install rails in the command line to install Rails. It seemed to install everything. It said "file 'lib' not found" a few times. I'm not sure if that is a problem. Then I ran rails new path/to/your/new/application

It created a lot of stuff in that directory but at the end had a problem:

```
Gem: InstallError: The 'json' native gem requires installed build tools.
Please update your PATH to include build tools or download the DevKit from 'http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads' and follow the instructions at 'http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit' 
An error occurred while installing json (1.6.5), and Bundler cannot continue. Make sure that 'gem install json -v '1.6.5'' succeeds before bundling.
```

I went to both of those sites to figure out what to do next. I downloaded the Dev Kit and went about installing it.

Those instructions seemed to work. After I did that, I tried rails new path/to/your/new/application
 again and it finished without errors.
Then cd C:\www-app
and rails server
and it came up properly at http://localhost:3000/. Great.

So then I wanted a real web server that I could start up with Windows. Passenger is not supported on Windows. This wasn't obvious until I tried it. So then I decided to try Apache and use Mongrel through it. These instructions looked nice - http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2006/5/11/deploying-rails-on-windows-servers/

I've installed Apache before, no big deal. I then went through the RailsWithApacheAndMongrel.pdf to get it working through Apache and ran into a zillion problems. That document is way out of date. I had to make many changes to the commands but I did get WEBrick serving the demo Ruby app through Apache fine. When it came to the Reverse Proxy stuff I learned that the Ruby plugin they recommend does not support Rails 3.

Then I got errors trying to run Mongrel "because msvcrt-ruby18.dll is missing from your computer" even though I installed with -include-dependencies. I couldn't use Mongrel and finally gave up.

I really put in a good try. "Just run this command" is what all the instructions say, and it is never that easy. If anyone finds a halfway decent guide to RoR on Windows please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding deployment, I recommend Heroku. I worked with them in the past and I have a lot of good things to say about them. Easy to start and it's free for development.

Check out the [deployment section](http://www.startprogrammingnowbook.com/book/deployment) of the Start Programming Now book if you want to set it up.

Comment: hmm  .. spreading a reference to a book across the site might be considered ... spam. Please don't!

Comment: @kleopatra, agree, a link to buy a book is spam, the one I shared is free to read online. Which is no different from sharing a blog post with some useful resources.